# Coverting List to Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

How can I convert a python list to a dictionary by comparing value at index 2 and 3 respectively

```
['Tunnel0', 'up', 'up'] --> {'Tunnel0':'1'}
['Tunnel0', 'up', 'down']--> {'Tunnel0':'0'}
['Tunnel0', 'down', 'down']--> {'Tunnel0':'0'}
['Tunnel0', 'down', 'up']--> {'Tunnel0':'0'}
```

Any help is much appreciated?

Here is what I tried

```
a = ['Tunnel0', 'up', 'up']
TunnelStatus = {i:1 if a[1]==a[2] else 0 for i in a }
print(TunnelStatus)
>>>{'Tunnel0': 1, 'up': 1}

b = ['Tunnel0', 'up', 'down']
TunnelStatus = {i: 1 if b[1]==b[2] else 0 for i in b }
print(TunnelStatus)
>>>{'Tunnel0': 0, 'up': 0, 'down': 0}
```

Comment: if you know there is always three-element in list you dont have to use dictionary comprehension

Comment: Does each list have only one entry or are there lists such as ```['tunnel0','up,'up','tunnel1','up,'down']```?

Comment: `TunnelStatus = {a[0]:1 if a[1]==a[2]=='up' else 0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear to me whether you want a general solution for a list of length 3n or specifically for a list of 3 strings.

This will provide the solution in any case:

`TunnelStatus = {a[i]:1 if a[i+1] == a[i+2] == 'up' else 0 for i in range(0, len(a), 3)}`

This comprehension  iterates in jumps of 3 comparing the `i+1` and `i+2` variables.

Here is some output:

```
a = ['tunnel0','up','up','tunnel1','up','down','tunnel2','down','up',
    'tunnel3','down','down']
b = ['tunnel0','up','up']

{a[i]:1 if a[i+1] == a[i+2] == 'up' else 0 for i in range(0, len(a), 3)}
>>>{'tunnel0': 1, 'tunnel1': 0, 'tunnel2': 0, 'tunnel3': 0}

{b[i]:1 if b[i+1] == b[i+2] == 'up' else 0 for i in range(0, len(b), 3)}
>>>{'tunnel0': 1}
```

In your solution you are iterating over the whole list and comparing the constants `a[1]` and `a[2]`. Thus, You will receive multiple output keys in the dictionary with all values equal.

Comment: Thanks, IsaacDj for your response. This helped me understand what I was doing incorrectly.

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck as you advance in the subject

Answer (score 0):

You can use counter and create a list of dicts:

```
from collections import Counter
s = [['Tunnel0', 'up', 'up'],
['Tunnel0', 'up', 'down'],
['Tunnel0', 'down', 'down'],
['Tunnel0', 'down', 'up']]

d=[]
for item in s:
  if Counter(item)['up'] == 2:
     d.append({item[0]: 1})
  else:
     d.append({item[0]: 0})

d
```

output:

```
 [{'Tunnel0': 1}, {'Tunnel0': 0}, {'Tunnel0': 0}, {'Tunnel0': 0}]
```